# how to map front-end field names to db column names for sorting

Tags: sorting, spring-mvc, mybatis

I am working on a web app using Spring MVC 3, Spring Data Commons 1.4.1, and MyBatis 3. To support sorting, I find myself needing to map input field names used on the client side to names of corresponding columns in the database. For example, on the client side, an input field is called shortName while the name of the corresponding column in the database is SHORT_NAME. What is the best way to do it? Does Spring provide any support for this? Thanks.

Here's how I annotate field names in the domain class so that I can look them up later in the controller method below.

```
@Entity
public class Activity extends BaseDomainObject {
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Column(name="SHORT_NAME")
    private String shortName;

    @Column(name="START_TIME")
    private Date startTime;

    @Column(name="END_TIME")
    private Date endTime;

    @Column(name="LOCATION")
    private String location;

    public Activity()
    {

    }

    // getters and setters go here
}
```

Here's the method in the controller

```
public @ResponseBody Page<Activity> query(ActivityCriteria ac, Pageable p) {

    // translate the fiend name used in the front-end into the one used in the back-end
    List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
    java.util.Iterator<Order> iterator = p.getSort().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Order order = iterator.next();
        if (!StringUtils.isBlank(order.getProperty()) && order.getDirection() != null) {
            String columnName = mapFieldNameToColumnName(Activity.class, order.getProperty());
            Order newOrder = new Order(order.getDirection(), columnName);
            orders.add(newOrder);
        }
    }

    Pageable copy = new PageRequest(p.getPageNumber(), p.getPageSize(), new Sort(orders));

    return activityService.query(ac, copy);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I end up doing in the corresponding MyBatis mapper file.

```
    <select id="getListOfActivitiesWithConditions" resultMap="activityMap" parameterType="map">
    SELECT a.* FROM activity a 
     <include refid="search-conditions"/> 
     <if test="page.sort != null">
        <foreach item="order" index="index" collection="page.sort" open="order by" separator="," close=" ">
            <if test="order.property != null and order.property == 'shortName'">
                SHORT_NAME ${order.direction}
            </if>
            <if test="order.property != null and order.property == 'startTime'">
                START_TIME ${order.direction}
            </if>
        </foreach>
     </if>
     limit #{page.offset}, #{page.size}
    </select>
```